# CustomVision: Operation returned an invalid status code: 'NotFound'

Tags: c#, computer-vision, prediction, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the NuGet package `Microsoft.Cognitive.CustomVision.Prediction` version `1.2.0`. I created 1 trial project and trained it with a few images. Now when I try to call the API for a prediction using the `PredicionEndpoint`, the system throws an exception: `Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException`.

When I debug the code and inspect the exception, it says:

```
{"Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'"}
```

This is my code:

```
var attachmentStream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(imageUrl);

PredictionEndpoint endpoint = new PredictionEndpoint() {
 ApiKey = "MY_CORRECT_PREDICTION_KEY"
};

var predictions = new ImagePredictionResultModel();

try {
 predictions = endpoint.PredictImage(new Guid("MY_CORRECT_PROJECT_ID"), attachmentStream);
} catch (Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException exception) {
 await context.PostAsync(exception.Body.ToString());
 await context.PostAsync(exception.Data.ToString());
}

foreach(var c in predictions.Predictions) {
  Console.WriteLine($ "{c.Tag}: {c.Probability}");
}
```

attachmentStream is a correct stream of an image, I am able to output it to a project-specific view.

The exception gets thrown when calling `endpoint.PredictImage(...)`.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't like the GUID of the Project ID? Try using the `CustomVision.Training` NuGet package and with that you can get a list of projects. From there they can be filtered by project name. Once you get your project there, you can use the `Id` property for the `PredictImage` call.

Comment: I tried doing it this way but I get the same result. I also compared the retrieved GUID and the one I used before after but it was the same.

Comment: Hmmmes, do you need to use a stream? Would the image URL itself not work?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198000/customvision-api-returns-operation-returned-an-invalid-status-code-notfound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that you should mark one of the training interations as `default` as mentioned in the [GithUb issue I created](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-CustomVision-Windows/issues/19).

Comment: Sorry, I can not check anymore as I don't use custom vision anymore.

Comment: "Make as default" Link/Button does not exist in my case.

Comment: It could be that they updated the UI... I'm sorry, I don't work with CustomVision anymore so I can't help you.